# YouTube Video Being Embedded via JWPlayer, "Play on YouTube" gets cut off

Tags: youtube, tooltip, embed, overflow, jwplayer

I am using JWPlayer to embed several YouTube videos on a web site. In the bottom right hand corner, there's the usual YouTube logo.

The text/tooltip that appears on hover is getting clipped by the video or the video's container.

Inspecting all of the parent elements, I'm not seeing anything that's set to overflow:hidden. Anyone run into this, or better yet, have a solution to either move the tooltip, or make it so it is not clipped by the video,container or object?

Edit: I've got it live now, so there is an example of what's happening:
http://www.copycei.com/#home

If you start playing a video from the home page, hover over the ghosted YouTube logo in the bottom right hand corner, and you'll see the clipped tooltip. Was really hoping I could target the id/class of that bit and just position it slightly to the left, but can't seem to inspect and target it in Chrome. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LongTailVideo (makers of JW Player) have filed this as an actual bug with the Google API used for embedding YouTube video:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=2899

Looks like there's not a solution to this as of now.